# Swap columns in table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

**How do I change the order of columns in a table?** I have too many rows and doing this manually would be a horrible pain.

A MWE to get us going (let's get rid of Yoda!):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
        \hline \hline
        this & in & order & is \\ \hline\hline
        1    & 3  & 4     & 2  \\
        a    & c  & d     & b  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}     

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: honestly this may be done with a simple regular expression in your editor and will be _much_ more reliable and robust than doing it in tex macros.